# How can I match a pattern that occurs after a known pattern

Tags: regex, awk, match

Consider the format of a bind dns zone file:

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.mydomain";
    masters {
            192.168.5.15;
    };
};
```

...

repeated several more times for other zones in the conf file.

I need to discover in a script some details about the zone.conf file.

I know the domain I am looking for so I can regex for something like '^zone "mydomain.com"'

But I need to discover the file line that occurs first after the zone name I am looking at.

I also want to discover the ip address in the masters list.

Our configuration only has one master ip so I don't have to worry about multiple ip's.

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: This is not a good job for a regular expression. You should use a parser such as http://search.cpan.org/~hardaker/Net-DNS-ZoneFile-Fast-1.16/Fast.pm instead.

Comment: I think this question fits http://serverfault.com better.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can be used to isolate the right section of the dns file, then print the next line after a pattern matched:

```
# sed -n '/"mydomain.com"/,/^};$/{/^zone "mydomain.com"/{n;p}}' dnsfile
   type slave;
# sed -n '/"mydomain.com"/,/^};$/{/masters/{n;p}}' dnsfile
        192.168.5.15;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach here would be to use sed to first output the zone block you are interested in, and then grab just the lines you want.  This might look something like the following:

```
sed -n '/^zone "mydomain.com"/,/^};/p' zone.conf | sed -n -e '2p' -e '/[0-9]/p'
```

`2p` will print only the second line (first line after the zone name), and `/[0-9]/p` will print only lines that contain digits (ip address).

Answer (score 0):

To get the next line with trimmed IP:

```
awk -F';' '/^ *masters/ { getline; sub(/^ */, "", $1); print $0 }' file
```

#### OUTPUT

```
192.168.5.15
```

To get zone line:

```
awk -F';' '/^zone "mydomain.com"/ { getline; sub(/^ */, "", $1); print $0}' file
```

#### OUTPUT

```
192.168.5.15
```